# How to calculate the sum of the Integers I insert in EditText everytime I insert an Integer?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, integer

I have a RecyclerView with a single TextView in it. And i have an add Button and one EditText outside it that only accept Integers and add them to the RecyclerView when i press the add button. My question is  how to make it calculate the sum of all the Integers i insert to the EditText.

Example: lets say i entered 300 to the EditText in the first row will show 300 then if i insert 200 to the EditText i want show 500 in the second row (300 + 200) and so on.

here is my code

> activity_main.xml
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     tools:context="com.example.brecyclerview.MainActivity"
>     android:orientation="vertical">
>
>     <EditText
>         android:id="@+id/edit_ten"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:ems="10"
>         android:hint="Score"
>         android:inputType="numberSigned|number" />
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:orientation="horizontal"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>
>         <Button
>             android:id="@+id/btn_add"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:onClick="btn_add"
>             android:text="Add"
>             tools:ignore="OnClick" />
>
>         <Button
>             android:id="@+id/btn_undo"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:onClick="btn_undo"
>             android:text="Undo"
>             tools:ignore="OnClick" />
>
>         <Button
>             android:id="@+id/btn_new"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:onClick="btn_new"
>             android:text="New Game" />
>
>     </LinearLayout>
>
>
>     <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
>         android:id="@+id/recycleViewContainer"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
>         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>         tools:itemCount="8" />
>
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

> list_item.xml
>
> ```
>   <RelativeLayout
>       android:id="@+id/singleRow"
>       android:layout_width="match_parent"
>       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>       android:padding="8dp">
>
>       <ImageView
>           android:id="@+id/userImg"
>           android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>           android:layout_width="60dp"
>           android:layout_height="60dp" />
>
>       <TextView
>           android:id="@+id/pNametxt"
>           android:text="User Name"
>           android:textSize="20sp"
>           android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
>           android:maxLines="1"
>           android:layout_width="match_parent"
>           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>           android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/userImg"
>           android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/userImg"
>           android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
>           android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />
>
>
>
>   </RelativeLayout>
>
>   <View
>       android:layout_below="@+id/singleRow"
>       android:layout_width="match_parent"
>       android:layout_height="1dp"
>       android:background="#f2f2f2" />
> ```

> MainActivity.java
>
> ```
> import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
> import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
> import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
>
> import android.content.Intent;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.widget.Button;
> import android.widget.EditText;
> import android.widget.TextView;
> import android.widget.Toast;
>
> import java.util.ArrayList;
> import java.util.List;
>
> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
>     Button button;
>     Button button1;
>     Button button2;
>     EditText editText;
>     TextView personName;
>     RecyclerView recyclerView;
>     RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
>     RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
>
>     List<PersonUtils> personUtilsList;
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>         button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
>         button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_undo);
>         button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_new);
>         editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_ten);
>         personName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pNametxt);
>
>         recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleViewContainer);
>         recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
>
>         layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
>
>         recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
>
>         personUtilsList = new ArrayList<>();
>
>
>
>         //Adding Data into ArrayList
>
>
>         mAdapter = new CustomRecyclerAdapter(this, personUtilsList);
>
>         recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
>
>
>
>         button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View v) {
>                 if (v == button2) {
>                     MainActivity.this.finish();
>
>                     startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
>                 }}});
>
>
>
>         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View view) {
>
>                 int pNametxt;
>                 int total = 0;
>                 for (int i = 0; i<personUtilsList.size(); i++)
>                 {
>                     total += personUtilsList.get(i).getPersonName();
>                 }
>                 total = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
>
>
>
>                 layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
>                 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
>                 personUtilsList.add(new PersonUtils(total));
>                 mAdapter = new CustomRecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this, personUtilsList);
>                 recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
>                 editText.setText("");
>
>
>             }});
>
>
>
>
>
>     }}
> ```

> CustomRecyclerAdapter.java
>
> ```
> import android.content.Context;
> import android.view.LayoutInflater;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.view.ViewGroup;
> import android.widget.Button;
> import android.widget.TextView;
> import android.widget.Toast;
>
> import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
>
> import java.util.List;
>
>
>
> public class CustomRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
>
>     private Context context;
>     private List<PersonUtils> personUtils;
>
>     public CustomRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List personUtils) {
>         this.context = context;
>         this.personUtils = personUtils;
>     }
>
>     public static void remove(long i) {
>
>
>     }
>
>
>     @Override
>     public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
>         View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
>         ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
>         return viewHolder;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
>         holder.itemView.setTag(personUtils.get(position));
>
>         PersonUtils pu = personUtils.get(position);
>
>
>        holder.pName.setText(String.valueOf(pu.getPersonName()));
>
>
>
>     }
>
>
>     @Override
>     public int getItemCount() {
>
>         return personUtils.size();
>     }
>
>
>
>     public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
>
>         public TextView pName;
>         Button deleteButton;
>
>         public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
>             super(itemView);
>
>             pName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pNametxt);
>             deleteButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_undo);
>
>
>                 }
>
>
>
>     }
>
>
>
>
> }
> ```

> PersonUtils.java
>
> ```
> public class PersonUtils {
>
>     private Integer personName;
>
>     public Integer getPersonName() {
>         return personName;
>     }
>
>     public void setPersonName(Integer personName) {
>         this.personName = personName;
>     }
>
>     public PersonUtils(Integer personName) {
>         this.personName = personName;
>     }
>
>
> }
> ```

thank u in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you done it in your code, but with a simple mistake.

MainActivity.java in button listener

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<personUtilsList.size(); i++)
{
    total += personUtilsList.get(i).getPersonName();
}
total = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
```

The problem of it, that you have set a new value for `total` variable but it should be `+=` instead of `=` and your code will work as you wish InChaa'Allah.

But i have some notices about your coding way.

First, these lines are bad to write it like this.

```
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
personUtilsList.add(new PersonUtils(total));
mAdapter = new CustomRecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this, personUtilsList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

It will do all the Activity life cycle again, and will be a lot of CPU waste.

So you do it like this.

```
((CustomRecyclerAdapter) mAdapter).addPersonUtils(new PersonUtils(total));
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//will make the RecyclerView adapter to reload its data.
```

And in CustomRecyclerAdapter.java class i have added a new method just to add a new item to the personUtils ArrayList.

```
public void addPersonUtils(PersonUtils personUtil){
    personUtils.add(personUtil);
}
```

The code will be better this way.

Comment: thank u very much that was helpful but what i want is when i insert an integer to edittext i want it to be add to the last value in the recyclerciew like this:  first i insert 200 it will be in the first row then i insert 300 so it will be 500 in the second row then lets say i inserted 200 it will be 700, but the that you helped with it sums all the values in the recyclerview i hope you can help me, thank you.

Comment: You're Welcome Ahmed, Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

When user click add button, you can get last value from your array list and sum with value at edit text. Add total sum to your list.

You don't have to do it again.

```
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            personUtilsList.add(new PersonUtils(total));
            mAdapter = new CustomRecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this, personUtilsList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Just add your item in personUtilsList and call recyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged() method.